# tearing in object using displacement map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, displacement, height-map

im working on an object that has displacement. it has 4 sides that will be seen. the 2 long sides and the 2 short sides. the long sides have materials separate from the short sides although they are going for the same look. i gave the short side displacement but now it has these black tears and artifacts. how can i fix this?

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PAK-EuOpAxpPGKdCO7nRNcP3MnpV95hd/view?usp=sharing)

[image: F]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it this way:

- Apply the scale of your object in *Object* mode
- Right click > *Shade Smooth*
- In *Edit* mode, recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
- Create some vertical loopcuts
- Bevel the angles of the object, with 2 segments for example
- Mark the seams on the edges that won't be seen in your render, <kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap with the *Conformal* option in the *Operator* box:

[image]

- Select *Material.002* in the *Material* panel because this is the one that has been assigned to your faces (the one on the right side has *Material.003*, so change it to *Material.002*)
- In the material bring back the *Mapping* *Rotation* values to default (0°), choose 3 for the *Scale* for example
- Change the *Subdivision Surface* modifier from *Simple* to *Catmull-Clark*, otherwise you'll have a separation of the displacement on the angles. Disable the *Adaptive Subdivision* option. Choose a subdivision level of 3 for example
- Lower down the *Displacement* scale at 0.5 for example

[image]